# understanding go channel handling / buffer overflow

Tags: go, channel, buffer-overflow

I have inherited some code I am still trying to make sense of.  The core of it is this:

```
for msg := range this.out {
    for i, handler := range this.handlers {
        select {
        case handler <- msg:
        default:
            this.logger.Printf("Buffer overflow occurred for handler %s", this.names[i])
        }
    }
}
```

out is a `chan byte`
handlers is `[]chan []byte`

It *looks* like this is reading from out and writing to a handler from the array, and the default is to complain about a buffer overflow.  I think.

But I need details.  I am new to go and this is my first time dealing with chan.   So first question, is that actually what is happening here?   And if so ... how do I prevent the buffer overflow?

Comment: Looks to me that this is reading a `msg` from `out` and then attempting to write this `msg` into *all* channels in the `handlers` array. But, if any channel in `handlers` currently has a full buffer (or is an unbuffered channel that isn't ready to receive a message) instead of writing to that particular channel, the overflow message will be logged. That's what the code does, though without knowing the reason this code was written we can't tell you why.

Comment: It won't compile with handlers is `[]chan []byte`. Try to give a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
Go playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/UVDicgckQe-

Comment: To me, this code implies that it is not critical that each `handler` channel receive the message .   It may be intentional that the channel can be full and further messages are not delivered.  Make sure that the real bug is using the scary sounding "buffer overflow" phrase instead of "backoff client %s, it has fallen too far behind and will have to query for the lost messages later".  Without  knowing about the use case, it's impossible to say, but that code is suspect to me.  Woody's phrase "using channels as infrastructure" resonates with me.

Comment: It does compile.  go version is "go1.13.15 linux/amd64" if that makes any difference.

What could I do to ensure the handler keeps up.  tbh I don't even see what the handler is doing.  Almost certainly because of my unfamiliarity with how go channels work.  Setting it up is code like:

Comment: `
 port := mqPort
 out := make (chan []byte, bufsize)
 dist.Subscribe("mq:"+mqPort, out)
`

... where Subscribe is:

`
 func (this *Dist) Subscribe(name string, handler chan []byte) {
 this.names = append(this.names, name)
 this.handlers = append(this.handlers.handler)
 }
`

So the handler is the "out" that was created by the make() call and passed to the Subscribe() ... but where is it going?   It looks like it is a channel to nowhere, with just a buffer of a given size that fills up.   I don't see anything established to _do_ anything with whatever is added to that buffer.

Comment: (Sorry the code got mangled there ...)

Answer (score 2):

In Go, channels can be created in two ways:

```
c := make(chan []byte)
```

which creates a channel that will synchronize the sender and receiver. This means that the receiver will have to wait until data is sent by the sender, and the sender will have to wait until the receiver gets that data. However, by adding a buffer to the channel:

```
c := make(chan []byte, 100)
```

you're effectively desynchronizing the sender and receiver. In this case, the sender will block when the buffer is full and the receiver will block when the buffer is empty.

Now, I don't know what the capacity on `handler` is, but this is the general workflow you should expect:

1. Go will check if there is space in `handler` and if there is, `msg` will be written to the channel.
2. If there is not space then the error message will be logged.

What you actually do about buffer overflow is a little more tricky.

First, as a stopgap, you could increase the capacity on `handler` so that it can hold more messages. This may represent an actual fix if the problem is intermittent (i.e. large spikes in traffic). Otherwise, all you're doing is pushing the issue off for a time.

Second, you could horizontally scale the handlers on the other end of `handler` to process more messages, thereby ensuring that the channel doesn't overflow. The problem with this, however, is that you then have to worry about managing handlers at various capacity levels so then you get into auto-scaling and things like that.

Third, you could look at the code handling messages from `handler` and see if this could be redesigned to handle messages more efficiently. Such redesigns are pretty common when the original design assumptions for your code no longer hold.

Finally, you could move away from using channels as infrastructure altogether and replace that component with a cloud-based pub/sub that includes memory. The advantage here is that this would allow you to scale your application as necessary without worrying about overflow but it would incur additional costs and require infrastructure changes.

Comment: There is still some magic going on that I don't understand.  You created a channel for a hundred byte array buffer ... but a channel to _where_?   When I write to that buffer, where does it go?   Nothing in that "make()" explains this.   How is the code to handle bytes sent to that buffer linked to that buffer?  the programmer using the name "handler" for the channel here did not help things.  I don't know where the actual _handler_ code is!

Comment: I will have to look into this "pub/sub" option, got any links on where to read up on that?

Comment: @rimiha The `chan` type represents an object in Go. I cannot give you the precise details as it's something I'm fuzzy on as well. However, if two functions have access to `handler`, one can do `<-handler` to receive and the other can do `handler <- {something}` to send. In that send, the channel can connect two go routines under the same process.

Comment: @rimiha You could check out SQS/SNS on AWS, Event Grid, Event Hub or Service Bus on Azure, or NATS for a cloud-agnostic offering. You could also use TCP if you want to role your own. But, in general, `chan` is used to connect threads within the same application so you should be careful before you switch up your infrastructure.